# How is remaining inventory items in home business calculated in COGS on schedule C

Tags: united-states, income-tax, small-business, schedule-c

My wife recently stopped doing her home business which is an MLM clothing sales.  Though she cut ties with the company and ended her business in December 2022, she's still left over with a large inventory of clothing that she hasn't sold.  I'm doing our federal income taxes, and have some questions how that should be reported on the schedule C, and the effect on Cost of Goods Sold (COGS).  Her friend who recently quit the same company told her that she was advised by her accountant to report $0 on End of Year Inventory (EoYI).  To me that seems incorrect since that would add the cost of all of the inventory that she never sold, including BoYI to COGS, thus showing a smaller profit or even a loss ( which for income tax purposes would be great).

I was thinking it might be appropriate take a final inventory, and use that figure to calculate line 36 on Schedule C, which is "Purchases less cost of items withdrawn for personal use", where we would consider the remaining inventory personal use and subtract it from purchases of inventory.

I'm not sure it makes much of a difference, but I would like to keep everything above board. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Do you actually intend to use it or is it just trash now?

Comment: @littleadv She might use some and give away the rest; some to friends some to goodwill.  Of course i do realize that if she donates it now that it's too late to write of for her business for this year.  A since we wont be filing next year we can't write it off then.

Comment: I'm not a lawyer or a CPA, but it wouldn't sound unreasonable for me to zero it out.